# How would i Execute ajax validation in two database?one is API database and the other is a local one

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have this in my controller function in my view a typical username and password input form

```
public function login() {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    //if user dont exist in the in the local database it will be validated thru the API
    if(!$this->is_registered_email($_POST['username'])) {
        $ret = file_get_contents('http://www.XXXXd48170846c1e937640ae7e9f6743089c3c2a9074/auth/{"user":"' . $username . '","pass":"' . $password . '"}');
        $ret = json_decode($ret);
    } else {
        //this is where if the user exist in the local database and in the API database
        // and if the user input a wrong password

    }
    //this will return user details from the API if the user exists
    $data = array('response' => $ret);

}
```

i added the comment to the process

Comment: why relay on javascript validation validate server side.

Comment: because the page should not be reloaded

Comment: use ajax but i am saying validate server side .

Comment: Server side validation is what i think you should be doing http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html